# How to edit files from database?

Tags: php, mysql

i have made a register form that keeps all of the created users in the database. Now, i want to put button (link, whatever) next to each of the created user, and when i click on the button, new login form to be shown, after i fill all of the required fields and press on update button, the edited user to be shown in database. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Code:

register form:

```
<?php 
$errors = [];
$missing = [];
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Facebook login</title>   
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<?php if(isset($_POST['send']) && count($missing) == 0){
    echo "Thank you for register on our site! You profile details are listed bellow:";
    ?>
        <p>Your name: <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?></p>
        <p>Lastname name: <?php echo $_POST['lastName']; ?></p>
    <?php
}else{
?>

<h1>Registration</h1>


<form method="post" action="register_user.php">

    <?php if ($errors || $missing) : ?>
        <p class="warning"> Please fill all of the empty items

        </p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <p>
    <label for="username">Username
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('username', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your first name</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </p>


    <p>
    <label for="password">Enter your password
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('password', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your password</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">


    <p>
    <label for="re-password">Re-Enter your password
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('re-password', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please re-enter your password</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <input type="re-password" name="re-password" id="re-password">
    </p>



    <p>
    <label for="name">First Name
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('name', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your first name</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="firstName">
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('lastName', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your last name</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <input type="name" name="lastName" id="lastName">
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="email">Enter your email adress
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('email', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please enter your email adress</span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </p>

    <h3>Birthday</h3>
    <p>
    <label for="Select Month"> Select Month
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('month', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please select month</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <select name="month" id="month" >
    <option value="Month"> Month </option>
    <option value="Jan"> January </option>
    <option value="Feb"> February </option>
    <option value="Mar"> March </option>
    <option value="Apr"> April </option>
    <option value="May"> May </option>
    <option value="June"> June </option>
    <option value="July"> July </option>
    <option value="Aug"> August </option>
    <option value="September"> September </option>
    <option value="Oct"> October </option>
    <option value="Nov"> November </option>
    <option value="Dec"> December </option> 
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="Select Day"> Select Day
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('day', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please select Day</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <select name="day" id="day" >
    <option value="Day"> Day </option>
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
    <option value="6"> 6 </option>
    <option value="7"> 7 </option>
    <option value="8"> 8 </option>
    <option value="9"> 9 </option>
    <option value="10"> 10 </option>
    <option value="11"> 11 </option>
    <option value="12"> 12 </option>
    <option value="13"> 13 </option>
    <option value="14"> 14 </option>
    <option value="15"> 15 </option>
    <option value="16"> 16 </option>
    <option value="17"> 17 </option>
    <option value="18"> 18 </option>
    <option value="19"> 19 </option>
    <option value="20"> 20 </option>
    <option value="21"> 21 </option>
    <option value="22"> 22 </option>
    <option value="23"> 23 </option>
    <option value="24"> 24 </option>
    <option value="25"> 25 </option>
    <option value="26"> 26 </option>
    <option value="27"> 27 </option>
    <option value="27"> 27 </option>
    <option value="28"> 28 </option>
    <option value="29"> 29 </option>
    <option value="30"> 30 </option>
    <option value="31"> 31 </option>    
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="Select Year"> Select Year
    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('year', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please select year</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <select name="year" id="year" >
    <option value="Year"> Year </option>
    <option value="1990"> 1990 </option>
    <option value="1991"> 1991 </option>
    <option value="1992"> 1992 </option>
    <option value="1993"> 1993 </option>
    <option value="1994"> 1994 </option>
    <option value="1995"> 1995 </option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="Select gender"> Select gender 

    <?php 
    if ($missing && in_array('Select gender', $missing)) : ?>
        <span class="warning"> Please select your gender</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="malegender">
    <label for="gender" > Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="femalegender">
    <label for="gender"> Female</label>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="send">

</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for the registered user:

```
Register user:

<?php 
$errors = [];
$missing = [];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $firstname = $_POST["name"];
    $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $month = $_POST["month"];
    $day = $_POST["day"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $gender = $_POST["gender"];

    if (!isset($_POST['username']) || strlen($_POST['username']) < 3) {
      $missing[] = "username";
    }else{
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || strlen($_POST['name']) < 3) {
      $missing[] = "name";
    }else{
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['lastName'])|| strlen($_POST['lastName']) < 3) {
      $missing[] = "lastName";
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || strlen($_POST['email']) < 3 ) {
      $missing[] = "email";
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['re-password']) || strlen($_POST['re-password']) < 3 ) {
      $missing[] = "re-password";
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['password']) || strlen($_POST['password']) < 3 ) {
      $missing[] = "password";
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['month']) || $_POST['month'] == "Month" ) {
      $missing[] = "month";
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['year']) || $_POST['year'] == "Year" ) {
      $missing[] = "year";
    }

if (!isset($_POST['day']) || $_POST['day'] == "Day") {
  $missing[] = "day";
}

if (!isset($_POST['gender'])) {
  $missing[] = "Select gender";
}


if(count($missing) > 0){
    echo "validation error!!!";
}else{


    $dsn = "mysql:host=";
    $host = "localhost";
    $db = "registration";

    $dsn .= $host.";";
    $dsn .= "dbname=".$db;

    $user = 'root';

    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user);

    $selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM register_table WHERE username = :username OR email_adress = :email";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($selectQuery);

    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

        echo "User exists!!!";
    }else{
        $stmtInsert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO register_table (username, password, first_name, last_name, email_adress, month, day, year, gender) VALUES (:username, :password, :name, :lastName, :email, :month, :day, :year, :gender)");

        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':name', $firstname);
        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':lastName', $lastName);
        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':month', $month);
        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':day', $day);
        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':year', $year);
        $stmtInsert->bindParam(':gender', $gender);

        $stmtInsert->execute();

        $arr = $stmtInsert->errorInfo();

        print_r($arr);

        echo "New records created successfully!!!";
    }


    $editQuery = "SELECT username FROM register_table";
    $editResult = mysql_query($editQuery);

    while($user = mysql_fetch_array($editQuery))


    $dbh = null;
}

}
```

Comment: i really cant understand you , can explain one more time plz =)

Comment: - I want to put edit button for every user next to him. When i click on edit button, i want to edit informations for that user.

Comment: Just carry out an update query for the given user. Its hard to help you because you haven't posted any code for your question. Also never store a password in plain text like you have done here.

Comment: which page you want the update button to be ? cause i only see the page you liked which is "register" page

Comment: Now i have edited the question. The edit button i want to be in the register user script.

Answer (score 0):

This is code I use on my database 2 sets of code - view.php displays the records with an option to edit next to each record in the list then if you click on edit it opens edit.php displaying a form to change and save the details.  If you need it I can send the table structure and contents as well.  There is quite a lot of code but I want to give the whole picture of a working system that I think does exactly what you want.  It is mysql but I am converting to mysqli

view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
/*
VIEW.PHP
Displays all data from 'players' table
*/
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');
// get results from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats")
or die(mysql_error());
// display data in table
echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>date</th> <th>Home Team</th> <th></th><th></th><th>Away Team</th> <th></th> <th></th> </tr>";
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// echo out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['hometeam'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['fthg'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['ftag'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['awayteam'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
// close table>
echo "</table>";
?>
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

edit.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
/*
EDIT.PHP
Allows user to edit specific entry in database
*/
// creates the edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($id, $hometeam, $awayteam, $error)
{
// if there are any errors, display them
if ($error != '')
{
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<div>
<p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
<strong>First Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="hometeam" value="<?php echo $hometeam; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Last Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="awayteam" value="<?php echo $awayteam; ?>"/><br/>
<p>* Required</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');
// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
// get form data, making sure it is valid
$id = $_POST['id'];
$hometeam = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['hometeam']));
$awayteam = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['awayteam']));
// check that hometeam/awayteam fields are both filled in
if ($hometeam == '' || $awayteam == '')
{
// generate error message
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
//error, display form
renderForm($id, $hometeam, $awayteam, $error);
}
else
{
// save the data to the database
mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET hometeam='$hometeam', awayteam='$awayteam' WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());
// once saved, redirect back to the view page
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
else
{
// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
echo 'Error!';
}
}
else
// if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
{
// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{
// query db
$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE id=$id")

or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
if($row)
{
// get data from db
$hometeam = $row['hometeam'];
$awayteam = $row['awayteam'];
// show form
renderForm($id, $hometeam, $awayteam, '');
}
else
// if no match, display result
{
echo "No results!";
}
}
else
// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
{
echo 'Error!';
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```